# How do I resolve a conversion varchar error?

Tags: varchar

[image]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Avgas 100LL' to data type int.

```
USE CBS_AFRICA_LIVECOPY

SELECT 
    ORDERS.CDRS_ORDER_ID, ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID, 
    FOLIO_HISTORY.FOLIO_NUMBER, MOVEMENT_NUMBER AS ORDER_MOVEMENT_NUMBER,
    SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.NAME, ORDERED_QUANTITY, 
    NET_QUANTITY, NAME, 
    FORMAT(FOLIO_HISTORY.OPEN_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS FOLIO_OPEN_DATE, 
    FORMAT(FOLIO_HISTORY.CLOSE_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS FOLIO_CLOSE_DATE,
    STATUS,  
    FORMAT(TERM_START_LOAD_TIME, 'HH') AS TERM_START_LOAD_TIME, 
    FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME, 'HH') AS TERM_END_LOAD_TIME, TERMINAL_NAME 
FROM 
    ORDERS 
INNER JOIN 
    TERMINAL_OWNER ON ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = TERMINAL_OWNER.TERMINAL_ID
INNER JOIN 
    FOLIO_HISTORY ON ORDERS.FOLIO_NUMBER = FOLIO_HISTORY.FOLIO_NUMBER 
                  AND FOLIO_HISTORY.Terminal_ID = ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID
INNER JOIN 
    ORDER_LOADED ON ORDERS.CDRS_ORDER_ID = ORDER_LOADED.CDRS_ORDER_ID
JOIN 
    SUPPLIER_PRODUCT ON ORDERS.SUPPLIER_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.NAME
WHERE 
    FOLIO_HISTORY.FOLIO_NUMBER >= '20190201'
    AND ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = 1900
```

The expected results should show the product name in my results query

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Avgas 100LL' to data type int.

[[image: Error[1]]

Comment: Basically you can see the product code result in my code, but I want to add the product name which gives me the varchar error.

Comment: You appear to be using a varchar value somewhere, perhaps in a comparison, where it is being converted to an int, but that isn't possible (just look at the value in your error message).

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to SQL queries and learning as I go along.  Is the error related to the product name having both numeric and text values?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: The sample data is in my code attached, unless you mean something else?  The query runs fine but as soon as I join the table JOIN SUPPLIER_PRODUCT ON ORDERS.SUPPLIER_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.NAME it gives this error.

Comment: Yes, and look at the error message.  Does `Avgas 100LL` look like an integer to you?  The problem here is that the other side of the comparison is an integer, and so SQL Server is trying to cast `Avgas 100LL` to an int, but it is failing.

Comment: Can it be fixed and if so please tell me how?

Comment: Visit this site [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and setup a demo with working data.  Paste the link here and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, but if you don't want to help or cant help - just say so.

Comment: Hi, I am still struggling to convert this string - could anyone possible give me an idea?